# Prove that two propositions $φ$ and $ψ$ are syntactically equivalent if and only if the proposition $φ↔ψ$ is a tautology

Tags: propositional-calculus

$φ↔ψ$ is a tautology.

Does it mean $φ↔ψ$ is always true? If so, then we can derive $φ\rightarrowψ$ and $φ\leftarrowψ$. But we have to prove $φ⊢ψ$ and $ψ⊢φ$. What's the difference?

Comment: Yes : true for every truth assignement.

Comment: If you have the *Deduction Th*, you can use it to derive, from $\varphi \vdash \psi$ : $\vdash \varphi \to \psi$.

Comment: @Mauro I'm trying to figure out comment 2. Comment 3 makes me more confuse. What is semantically equivalent? It seems like a computer science term.

Comment: @Mauro $φ↔ψ$  is a tautology. Then $φ\rightarrowψ$ is a tautology. This gives $⊢φ→ψ$, so $φ⊢ψ$. Correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In propositional logic, we have that $\varphi \leftrightarrow \psi$ is a *tautology* (in symbols : $\vDash \varphi \leftrightarrow \psi$) iff it is *true* for every truth assignement.

We say that two formulas $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are [syntactically equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence) iff $\varphi \leftrightarrow \psi$ is a theorem. In symbols : $\vdash \varphi \leftrightarrow \psi$

Thus, we have to "link" the semantical notion of *tautology* to the syntactical notion of *theorem* of the (propositional) calculus (Natural Deduction, Truth Trees, or other).

If we are working in Natural Deduction, the rule for $↔$-introduction allows use to conlcude with $\vdash \varphi \leftrightarrow \psi$ from :

> $\vdash \varphi \rightarrow \psi$ and $\vdash \psi \rightarrow \varphi$.

*Note*: see [Soundness and completeness of propositional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Soundness_and_completeness_of_the_rules) : $\vdash \sigma$ **iff** $\vDash \sigma$.